# do multiplication and display the result in foreign script with expl3

Tags: expl3, polyglossia

I'm trying to make a macro able to do a simple arithmetical operation and which will display the result beside their equivalent in a foreign script. I'm trying to do it in `expl3` with use of `\tl_put_right:Nn` or `:Nx`. My try is leading to a weird result. I'm expecting something like this "30 = ३०", "40 = ४०"...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
  \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{NotoSans}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}
\newcommand{\sam}[1]{\textsanskrit{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_mystack_tl
\NewDocumentCommand\putnumbers { m m } {
  \tl_put_right:Nx { #1 } { \int_eval:n { 10 * #2 } }
  \tl_put_right:Nx { #1 } { = \devanagaridigits{ \int_eval:n { 10 * #2 } } }
\tl_use:N #1
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $\putnumbers{\l_mystack_tl}{3}$

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tl_put_right:Nx { #1 }`  here N arguments should not have braces, but I don't think you need #1 at all do you, since you immediately typeset? if you do want to save in a command,  use `\foo` not `\l_mystack_tl` as you can not use `_` in command names in the document

Comment: `\l_mystack_tl` is a variable, it can be called `command` too here? I need to use a variable since in my original code it is not immediately typeset.

Comment: after `\ExplSyntaxOff` L3 syntax like `\l_mystack_tl` can not be used

Comment: `\l_mystack_tl` is used as an argument to a macro defined in the expl3 environment. Nevertheless I tried with `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` respectively before and after `\putnumbers...` and that does not change anything.

Comment: that is not a reference to the l3 variable it is \l subscript m ystac k subscript t l  you can not change catcides in a beamer frame unless you use the fragile option

Comment: sorry typo: catcodes not catcides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You need to access the L3 variable using document conventions, I used `c` here so the name Could be constructed.

Also do the arithmetic before applying devanagaridigits and I used `\text` as the font is not set up in math mode.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{metropolis}}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
  \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{NotoSans}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}
\newcommand{\sam}[1]{\textsanskrit{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_mystack_tl
\NewDocumentCommand\putnumbers { m m } {
  \tl_put_right:cx {l_ #1 _tl } { \int_eval:n { 10 * #2 } }
  \tl_put_right:cx {l_ #1 _tl } { = 
    \exp_not:N\text{\exp_not:N\devanagarifontsf{
        \exp_not:N\devanagaridigits{ \int_eval:n { 10 * #2 } } }}}
\tl_use:c {l_ #1 _tl }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $\putnumbers{mystack}{3}$

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i tried by using `l_mystack_tl` and `#1` in the macro definition instead of `l_ #1 _tl`, it worked. Why did you add `\devanagarifontsf`? I think it requires a deep understanding of how `expl3` and `beamer` have been implemented to be able to write such a code. What is `catcides`?

Comment: @user1850133 the answer here doesn't really depend on beamer or expl3, I used `\devanagaridigits` as in your question, tex reported that computer modern font does not have `३` it seems that command changes the character but you still need to specify a font so I added `\devanagarifontsf`

Comment: "i tried by using `l_mystack_tl` and `#1` in the macro definition instead of `l_ #1 _tl`, it worked." yes that would work of course but it is bad style to expose internal l_... names in the document so it seemed best just to make the argument `mystack` and construct the rest of the name internally. @user1850133

Comment: As for the `\devanagarifontsf`, it's strange that tex was looking for `computer modern`. The commands `\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf...` `\setmainlanguage` and `\setmainfont` are all set so that `NotoSansDevanagari` is the default font for the whole document. In my case it works without that additional `\devanagarifontsf`.

Comment: @user1850133 all those are text font declarations but you were using math so sans serif digits coming from cmss. Ah but I added `\text{..}` later so yes probably it would pick up the text font without that, you are right